# No module named 'tensorflow' with GCP

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When trying to execute a *gcloud ai-platform local train* command with python 3.7 files, I get an error like:
No module named 'tensorflow'

This can happen also with numpy, even though both of these libraries are correctly installed. Is there a different installation path for libraries in Google Cloud? I am actually a newbie with GCP and I have no idea of what may be causing this problem. I am working on a Mac and Google SDK is, I guess, correctly installed.

Thanks

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UA0A.png)

Comment: The package name is all lowercase, python is a case sensitive language.

Comment: they are regularly imported, lowercase

Answer (score 0):

[Naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) of packages and modules are expected to be lowercase.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

I suspect the same issue arises with numpy - where you are incorrectly writing `import TensorFlow` or `import Numpy`

Comment: Sorry, clearly tensorflow and numpy are imported lowercase. My fault. I use them constantly, but dunno why with GCP they cause problems.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you say it's your fault - does that mean your question is answered? You say with GCP there are problems right afterward.

Comment: I've corrected the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an environment variable named `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` that must be set to `"python3.x"`.

My error was caused by GCP using `python2`, and so not recognizing certain packages.